# GCC and Clang disagree about constexpr-ness of lambda?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, metaprogramming, constexpr

Why does Clang fail to compile the following code, with the message that the expression is not constexpr, and why does GCC not? Which compiler is correct?
https://godbolt.org/z/nUhszh
(Obviously, this is just an example. I do, in fact, need to be able to invoke a constexpr function-object in a constexpr context.)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Predicate>
constexpr int f(Predicate&& pred) {
    if constexpr (pred(true)) {
        return 1;
    } 
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    f([](auto m) {
        return std::is_same_v<decltype(m), bool>;
    });
}
```

Output of clang 8.0.0 with `-std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -O1 -march=skylake`:

```
<source>:5:19: error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression

    if constexpr (pred(true)) {

                  ^

<source>:14:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'f<(lambda at <source>:14:7)>' requested here

    f([](auto m) {

    ^

1 error generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang is right. In the expression `pred(true)`, the *id-expression* `pred` denotes a variable of reference type. Variable of reference type can appear in constant expression only if they are initialized by a constant expression or if their initialization is performed during the evaluation of the expression ([[expr.const]/2.11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref)).

So `pred(true)` is not a constant expression.

If you change the declaration of the parameter `pred` to `Predicate pred`, `Pred` will not be of reference type. The expression `pred(true)` will be equivalent to `pred.operator()(true)`. `pred` will be an *object-expression* in a [class member access expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref), and as such, no *lvalue-to-rvalue* conversion will be applied to `pred`. So the *id-expression* `pred` will not have to be initialized by a *constant expression* (see [[expr.const]/2.7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.7.3)) in order to be a *constant expression*. Then the function call is a *constant expression* because the call operator is implictly a constexpr function [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.closure#4).

Those facts justify the proposal of @NikosC. to declare `Pred` as `Predicate Pred`. In this case your code will compile with both Clang and Gcc and will be standard compliant.

Comment: Well, can't deny there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion here. I'm still stumped by the fact the lambda doesn't have to be `constexpr` though. It's calling a non-constexpr function in an `if constexpr`, wth? Edit: NVM: "satisfies the requirement of a constexpr function". <smh>

Answer (score 3):

By using the predicate in an `if constexpr` you expect it to be unconditionally a constant expression. But a `constexpr` function can *always* be called in a non-constexpr context with arguments that are not constant expressions. So a function parameter may *never* be assumed to be a constant expression.

GCC is therefore wrong to accept your code unmodified.

It just so happens that your specific example doesn't require an `if constexpr` to work in a constexpr context. A modified function:

```
template <typename Predicate>
constexpr int f(Predicate&& pred) {
    if (pred(true)) {
        return 1;
    } 
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is invocable by [both compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/IVvqT3) when a constant expression is required:

```
int main() {
    constexpr int i = f([](auto m) constexpr {
        return std::is_same_v<decltype(m), bool>;
    });
    return i;
}
```

Comment: @NikosC. I would ask you to post this as an answer so I can mark the question as solved.

Comment: @paladin324 That wouldn't be an answer though. The question is "why doesn't clang accept it", not how to make it accept it :-)

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot accept that as a solution, as invoking a function-object in a constexpr context is what I am trying to do. I cannot rely on a runtime-check for other reasons. (I rely on the compile-time check to alternate the return type of f()).

Comment: @NikosC. - Everything I know about constant expressions tells me it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @paladin324 - Sure, you can take by value and rely on a pair of compiler bugs that may very likely be fixed right under you. But I'd consider refactoring if I were you. And it's perfectly fine not to accept an answer, no need to apologize.

Comment: @paladin324 Do not worry about it becoming a runtime check. The compiler will be able to eliminate one of the branches and there won't be a check. This has been an optimization long before `if constexpr` came along. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/VMf7rk There is no runtime branch.

Comment: I am just not convinced that the bug is what you mentioned. The reason for that is that if constexpr requires its "argument" to always be evaluated at compile-time (it is not context-dependent).

Comment: @paladin324 - Exactly, that's the problem. The argument doesn't have to be a constant expression. The function has no knowledge if it's invoked "normally" or as part of evaluating a constant expression. That's exactly why it **may not** assume the argument is a constant expression.

Comment: @NikosC. I am not worried about the runtime overhead. I want to employ this in a metaprogramming context. (Being able to use a constexpr lambda to provide a predicate, instead of relying on type-level implemented checks) .